# Combining soft body with deform modifiers (scale, armature, morphs...)

Tags: modifiers, physics

I'm trying to make an effect like a balloon, but on a blob like creature. I'm looking for a way to combine soft body physics with keyframing the scale of an object, since full strength physics disable it. Picture a balloon getting bigger in a room until it squeezes through the windows. I'm trying to achieve that WITHOUT using pressure or length, but something I could keyframe. Is it possible?

Comment: Both pressure and length *are* keyframable.  But there are other ways.  Are you okay with cloth physics or does it need to be specifically SB?

Comment: I'm not sure it's feasible to drive the length from the object's scale, in the end I just used goal without springs, it's enough to make the mesh follow the transformations.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is a straight forward case of scaling firstly, then shapekeying to pull the swollen sphere's surface back inside the building's interior.  (Blend file below)

[image]

A 2nd shapekey was used to pull the balloon's surface out the window.
(I left the bottom window for you to have a go)

-========-

Notes -

The sphere's (balloon's) swelling was by scaling a Circle-Empty acting as a parent to the sphere.  A parent was used because further modification & animation would be required to the sphere's mesh for the extrusion and arguably, a safer way to operate. (no conflict surprises)

The 2nd shapekey pulling the balloon out through the window requires some very minor subdivision at the balloon's mid-right side (and close to the window frame's borders) in order to crease/fold the surface and force it into a square-shaped, soft 90 degree extrusion.

Turning on 'Proportional Editing' can make things easier but some tweaking adjustments are better served with it turned off.

[image]